# Android Studio cannot resolve Views, not autocompleting

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner android developer, and I am running into this infuriating problem.
When writing in java, the IDE doesn't seem to recognize any of my imports, stating that it **'cannot resolve'** any kind of views.

Furthermore, on the activity xml, it says, for all the xml elements, that the '**element is not allowed here**'.

Funny thing is, only for certain projects that android studio behaves this way.And all of my projects were created and edited in the same way.
**Invalidating cache/restart does not work**.

Comment: Did you have the sdk setuped ?

Comment: i think there is some thing wrong with your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your SDK if you have setuped sdk path.